# Pipe dcraw output as input to cjpeg.exe

Tags: windows

Here is the command i'm trying in windows powershell.

```
 .\dcraw-9.27-ms-64-bit.exe -c "C:\Downloads\RAW_CANON_10D.CRW" | cjpeg\cjpeg.exe temp.jpg
```

But cjpeg isn't getting the input and show this message.
[image]

Comment: OK so I opened for bounty, suddenly a downvote. Care explaining why mr. downvoter?

Comment: People down-votes when the question is not clear enough to understand, lacks proper details or contains images of code/output. edit the question to add some more info, like what `dcraw` is, what it outputs, and what `cjpeg` is, why you want to pipe them rather using different commands.

Comment: Why is there a C# tag?

Comment: I will use this command in c# application.

Comment: OK, but there is nothing about this question as it stands which relates to C#. I daresay that may be the source of the downvote.

Comment: There are Linux `man` pages for [dcraw](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dcraw) and [cjpeg](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cjpeg) indicating that your command should be valid; but that error message seems to indicate that the Windows version of cjpeg you're using does not accept STDIN. Either find a different version of cjpeg or go via a temporary intermediate file, rather than piping.

Comment: I don't have downvoted but I hesitate for same reason as Munim Munna that I have posted (for me) the best response. Putting an image to document console output is not a good practice. Posting a question without a ? character is not very good. We must guess what you really want. I think that you have chance that somebody has taken some times to post a good answer.

Comment: You are correct 100%, my apologies, was a long day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `cjpeg.exe` with both input and output arguments.

```
cjpeg.exe <input-file> <output-file>
```

You are calling `cjpeg.exe` with single argument generating the error.

```
cjpeg.exe temp.jpg
```

Actually you are trying to feed the result of the first command as the input of the `cjpeg` command. If `dcraw` returns the path of the input file then you have to execute the following:

```
.\dcraw-9.27-ms-64-bit.exe -c "C:\Downloads\RAW_CANON_10D.CRW" |
%{ cjpeg\cjpeg.exe $_ temp.jpg }
```

If `dcraw` returns raw binary output of the image you need to save it to a temporary file.

```
.\dcraw-9.27-ms-64-bit.exe -c "C:\Downloads\RAW_CANON_10D.CRW" |
Out-file temp.tiff |
%{ cjpeg\cjpeg.exe temp.tiff temp.jpg }
```

Comment: This response is clear and well documented. I think that m.qayyum suppose that input file is naturally got from input indirection; but for cjpeg.exe program it is not the case. The input file MUST BE specified as parameter not using input indirection.